# Logout on token expire next js next auth v4

Tags: next.js, next.js13, next-auth, next.js14

I have the following code in authOptions.ts in next js 14 with next auth v4. I'm using external jwt for backend.

```
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth"
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials"
import { JWT } from "next-auth/jwt"

const API_ENDPOINT =
  process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL || "http://myapp.test/api"


class CustomError extends Error {
  status: number;

  constructor(message: string, status: number) {
    super(message);
    this.name = this.constructor.name;
    this.status = status;
    Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
  }
}

const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      type: "credentials",
      name: "Email and Password",
      credentials: {
        email: { label: "Email", type: "email", placeholder: "Your Email" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        console.log(credentials)
        if (!credentials?.email || !credentials?.password) return null

        const { email, password } = credentials

        const res = await fetch(`${API_ENDPOINT}/auth/login`, {
          method: "POST",
          body: JSON.stringify({
            email,
            password,
          }),
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Accept: "application/json",
          },
        })

        const response = await res.json()
        if (res.ok) {
          return response.data
        } else {
          throw new CustomError(response.message, response.status);
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {

      if (user) {
        return { ...token, ...user }
      }

      return token
    },
    async session({ token, session }) {

      session.user = token.user
      session.authorization = token.authorization
      return session
    },
  },

  pages: {
    signIn: "/auth/login",
  },
}
export {authOptions}
```

My next-auth.d.ts

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";

declare module "next-auth" {
  interface Session {
    user: {
      id: number;
      email: string;
      name: string;
      status: string;
      avatar?:string;
    };

    authorization: {
      token: string;
      type: string;
      expiresAt: number
    };
  }
}

import { JWT } from "next-auth/jwt"

declare module "next-auth/jwt" {
  interface JWT {
    user: {
      id: number;
      email: string;
      name: string;
      status: string;
      avatar?:string;
    };

    authorization: {
      token: string;
      type: string;
      expiresAt: number
    };
  }
}
```

when the login is success i get the following response

```
  const { data: session } = useSession();
  console.log({ session });
{
    "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "User One",
        "email": "userone@example.com",
        "status": "active",
        "avatar": null
    },
    "expires": "2024-04-23T09:51:41.208Z",
    "authorization": {
        "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vYmVzc2VudGlhbHMudGVzdC9hcGkvYXV0aC9sb2dpbiIsImlhdCI6MTcxMTI3MzkwMSwiZXhwIjoxNzExMjc3NTAxLCJuYmYiOjE3MTEyNzM5MDEsImp0aSI6IlpzUjZyUHdHaHU1bVJVSEMiLCJzdWIiOiIxIiwicHJ2IjoiMjNiZDVjODk0OWY2MDBhZGIzOWU3MDFjNDAwODcyZGI3YTU5NzZmNyJ9.nplynjW_PgzeAPyBnDZJI0vp3Wv9ehpAdQqME12mzsE",
        "type": "bearer",
        "expiresAt": 1711277501
    }
}
```

in the above session data `expiresAt` is sent by the external server where `expires` is generated by next auth.

I want to expire session (sign out user) when token time expires. How do i configure/tell next auth to watch `expiresAt` as token time instead of `expires`.

Answer (score 0):

You asked "How do i configure/tell next auth to watch expiresAt as token time instead of expires?"

**The Answer: You just can't.**

Your server generated token and next-auth session do not work the same.

[Balázs Orbán](https://github.com/balazsorban44) from the core team says

> "The session expiry is not the same as a third party access token.
> next-auth rotates the session expiry, meaning whenever the client
> contacts the backend, it will update the session expiry date. (which
> is basically the cookie lifetime)
>
> with other words, the session doesn't have a fixed/absolute expiry
> time as usually access tokens have.
>
> If the user doesn't open the page for a while, the cookie will expire
> and will be removed automatically. so make sure the session expiry is
> always lower than your access token expiry date, if you cannot refresh
> the access token."

The rest of the discussion can be found on this link: https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/2790

Of course, you can still terminate the user's session once your server generated token expires. But this is another question which I will not address here.